# Bunching Estimator with Heterogeneous Elasticities - Saez (2010)

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, nonparametric

The bunching estimator is an estimator developed by [Saez (2010)](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~saez/saezAEJ10bunching.pdf) for kinks and [Kleven and Waseem (2013)](https://www.henrikkleven.com/uploads/3/7/3/1/37310663/kleven-waseem_qje2013.pdf) for notches in order to estimate the elasticity of taxable income.

I understand the estimator for the case of homogeneous elasticities, which is also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140263/excess-bunching-bunching-estimator-saez-2010?rq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131446/how-to-use-the-bunching-estimator-to-estimate-the-elasticity-of-taxable-income).

I do not understand the case for heterogeneous elasticities. Kleven and Waseem (2013) argue that for heterogeneous elasticities excess bunching is equal to:

$B=\int_e \int_{z^*}^{z^* + \Delta z_{e}^{*}} \tilde{h}_0(z,e)\ dz\ de \ \approx\ h_0(z^*)E[ z_{e}^{*}]$

Here $h_0(z)$ is the counterfactual density and $h_0(z) \equiv \int_e \tilde{h_0}(z,e)\ de$.  Taxable income is $z$, the elasticity is $e$ and $\Delta z_{e}^{*} $ is increasing in $e$. They also assume that $\tilde{h_0}(z,e)$ is locally constant in $z$.

How do they mathematically arrive at this approximation? Also, what is the intuition behind this result?

**References**

- Kleven, H. and Waseem, M. (2013). Using notches to uncover optimization frictions and structural elasticities: theory and evidence from Pakistan. *Quarterly Journal of Economics*. 128:669–723
- Saez, E. (2010). Do taxpayers bunch at kink points? *American Economic Journal: Economic Policy.* 2:180–212